# Months after implementing 301 redirects to a new domain name, the old domain still appears in Google but with snippets from the new domain

Tags: seo, google, redirects, duplicate-content

**Background**

I had a single domain with 2000+ articles on a wide range of topics. For several reasons, I decided to split this site into several smaller, distinct sites, each on a separate domain name.

I use a PHP script to redirect traffic from the old site to the new. I determined that there were too many redirects to place and manage in .htaccess so I used PHP / MySql to handle this. The redirect is a 301.

`<?php
header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
header("Location: http://example.com/some-page");
?>`

**The Problem**

It's been nearly 8 months now since I moved everything around. While Google has picked up all the new sites and is actively indexing them, the old site index still contains the URL for the pages which were moved. The confusing thing is it's got the meta title and description from the new site! The old page title had a distinct name which is not present on the listed pages, and the listed pages contain the name of the new site.

If I search for an exact page title it appears the same on the old and new sites. Clicking on the old site result correctly performs a redirect to the new.

*Example Listing:*

Page Title For Example Page | My New Domain (shows as example.com)

Page Title For Example Page | My New Domain (shows as my old domain name)

I've checked the response codes using an online redirect checker and it all looks good.

**The Questions**

How do I get Google to automatically remove the links indexed on the old site. Is it just a matter of time, or is something going on with the redirects. There are too many to manually remove using the webmaster tools.

Since the pages appear twice, are Google likely to be penilising me for duplicate content?

I can provide domain names and examples if it helps to diagnose the problem.

Comment: You say that you used "PHP / MySql to handle this", which sounds OK, but then you include a code sample that is simply a _blind_ redirect to the new site's home page - which would be very bad for SEO. Can you please clarify - does that code sample have anything to do with what you actually did?

Comment: That code sample is just representative of how the redirect is executed. The location is set from the db value returned from the logic.

Comment: That is the type of behavior I would expect if you used temporary redirects.   I suspect something is wrong with your redirects and they are not as permanent as you think.

Comment: That's what's confusing me. These are the raw response headers from a redirect checker. I've also tested using the Firefox developer toolbar which shows the same. These headers look correct to me.

`>>> http://myolddomain.com/oldpage/

> --------------------------------------------
> 301 Moved Permanently
> --------------------------------------------
Status: 301 Moved Permanently
Code: 301
Date: Tue, 05 Sep 2017 10:54:50 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.34
Location: http://mynewdomain.com/newpage/
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8`

Comment: And on the new link 
`>>> http://mynewdomain.com/newpage/

> --------------------------------------------
> 200 OK
> --------------------------------------------
Status: 200 OK
Code: 200
Date: Tue, 05 Sep 2017 10:54:50 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.34
Last-Modified: Tue, 29 Aug 2017 20:37:19 GMT
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 21508
Cache-Control: max-age=604800
Expires: Tue, 12 Sep 2017 10:54:50 GMT
Vary: Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8`

Comment: I agree with @StephenOstermiller.. or if you really have permanent redirects in place I would say that you haven't managed to redirect every url. If you miss redirecting some urls Google will see that and think that the old domain still is in use. Try to find the pages that are not caught by you redirects and fix them too.

Comment: If you explicitly search for the old URLs, Google will show them to you even if things are indexed with the new URLs. That's not a sign that anything's wrong or broken.

Comment: @JohnMueller he says he was searching for exact page titles though, so it doesn't sound like searching for old URLs is the problem here.

Comment: @TimTrott  Please share your actual URLs and searches.  Without them, we are all just guessing at this point.

Comment: Thanks for the assists so far. The old domain is timtrott.co.uk. If you search site:timtrott.co.uk in Google you should see several page titles ending with "Your Paranormal", "Perfect Astronomy" and "Azulia Designs" These are the "new" domains which the pages are redirected to, and the page titles are specific to the domain. Clicking the link takes you to the new site via a redirect.

Comment: I also checked the site index in webmaster tools, it did show an initial drop in index pages when I transitioned over, however, there are quite a few it just hasn't picked up (yet). The sitemaps do not contain the incorrect URLs, only the list of pages for that particular site. If it is just a matter of time then fine, but I'd like to eliminate any technical issues which could be preventing Google from reindexing or updating itself.